# Reverse for 'shop_cart' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am trying out Django Mezzanine. I have installed it with pip. After successful installation I added the Cartridge package via pip install -U cartridge. I have also included it in my Installed_Apps. I am able to see the package and able to tweak with it in admin panel. But when I try to go onto home page it is giving me the following error:-

```
Reverse for 'shop_cart' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Inside the debugger I am shown the following error at line 4 highlighed:-

```
1   {% extends "base.html" %}
2   {% load i18n %}

3   

4   {% block meta_title %}{% trans "Home" %}{% endblock %}

5   {% block title %}{% trans "Home" %}{% endblock %}
6   

7   {% block breadcrumb_menu %}
8   <li class="active">{% trans "Home" %}</li>
9   {% endblock %}
10  
11  {% block main %}
12  {% blocktrans %}
13  <h2>Congratulations!</h2>
14  <p>
```

Also to mention that I have not edited any urls or any files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [read the manual](http://cartridge.jupo.org/overview.html) which tells you that after you install cartidge with `pip`, you have to create a new project with the correct template in order to include all the specific settings for cartridge, which include the URLs:

> Once installed, the command mezzanine-project can be used to create a
>   new Mezzanine project, with Cartridge installed, in similar fashion to
>   django-admin.py:
>
> ```
> $ mezzanine-project -a cartridge project_name
> $ cd project_name
> $ python manage.py createdb --noinput
> $ python manage.py runserver
> ```

For now, you can try adding these two lines to your `urls.py`, and it should get rid of the immediate problem, but you should really follow the instructions and create a project with the right template:

```
from cartridge.shop.views import order_history

url("^shop/", include("cartridge.shop.urls")),
url("^account/orders/$", order_history, name="shop_order_history"),
```

Comment: As I was trying it out for the first time I first did pip install mezzanine. Then did pip install -U cartridge. So I had to manually include the urls and app in the Installed apps

Comment: Thank you Burhan Khalid.